# Assigning to a numpy array using zip in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Thanks for the help everyone.  What seems to explain my problem the most concisely is that *zip* returns an iterator of tuples, not lists, and are therefore immutable.  You can see the working solution below and the original question code below that.

Solution:

```
f = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
trials = [[0,1,2], [5,6,7], [8,9]]
trial_averages = []
for i in trials:
    a = 0
    for j in i:
        a += f[j]
    a /= len(i)
    trial_averages.append(a)
trial_averages = np.array(trial_averages)
print('trials = {0}'.format(trials))
print('averages = {0}'.format(trial_averages))

trials = [[0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
averages = [ 2.   7.   9.5]
```

---

Question:

I am trying to modify elements of a numpy array in a for loop with a zip of two arrays and the modified array isn't getting updated.  What am I missing?

I've created a new example as my original one didn't seem to be illustrative of my exact issue.

New example:

```
f = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
trials = [[0,1,2], [5,6,7], [8,9]]
trial_averages = np.zeros(len(trials))
for i, j in zip(trials, trial_averages):
    for k in i:
        j += f[k]
    j /= len(i)
print('trials = {0}'.format(trials))
print('averages = {0}'.format(trial_averages))
print('{0}, {1}'.format(i, j))
```

Outputs:

```
trials = [[0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
averages = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
[8, 9], 9.5
```

In this case, *j* is a pointer to the element in *trial_averages*, which I expect to be updated in the second for loop to a sum of the values in *f* pointed to by the list in *trials*, then divided by the length of the list in *trials*, computing an average of the values of *f* in each trial.

---

Old example for reference:

Working example:

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=float)
B = np.zeros(len(A))
for i, j in zip(A, B):
    j = i
print('A = {0}'.format(A))
print('B = {0}'.format(B))
print('{0}, {1}'.format(i, j))
```

Outputs:

```
A = [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
B = [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
4.0, 4.0
```

Doesn't zip pass a pointer to the element in the input array?  Shouldn't the assignment j = i make B = [1. 2. 3. 4.]?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: _Doesn't zip pass a pointer to the element in the input array?_ Even if it did it wouldn't work because `j=i` does nothing beyond binding the name 'j' to whatever object is bound to the name 'i'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python it is important to know what happens when you do an assignment.  Does it assign a new object to the variable, or does it modify a (mutable) object.

In your code `j` is an element of a 1d array.  But `j=i` assigns to `j` the same object that was assigned to `i`.  This breaks all connection with the object produced by iteration.

In contrast, iterating on the rows of a 2d array:

```
In [439]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [440]: B = np.zeros_like(A)
In [441]: for i, j in zip(A,B):
     ...:     print(i, j)
     ...:     j[...] = i
     ...:     
[0 1 2 3] [0 0 0 0]
[4 5 6 7] [0 0 0 0]
[ 8  9 10 11] [0 0 0 0]
In [442]: B
Out[442]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Here, `i` and `j` are 1d arrays, views of their respective 2d arrays.  `j[...] =...` changes the values of the `j` array, and hence are reflected in the parent array, `B`.

`+=` is another in-place operation, producing the same change to `B`:

```
In [444]: for i, j in zip(A,B):
     ...:     j += i
```

Note that these rules apply to iterating on lists as well, though how the change back-propagates to the parent is different.  So it is important to understand what happens with `j=i` versus `j[:]=i` (and not just within a loop).  At the same time, don't get in the habit of working with arrays in this way.  Try to do the job without iterating on the arrays.

A list example:

```
In [446]: Al = A.tolist(); Bl = B.tolist()
In [447]: for i,j in zip(Al, Bl):
     ...:     j[:] = i[::-1]   # assign a reverse list
     ...:     # j =  would not work
In [449]: Bl
Out[449]: [[3, 2, 1, 0], [7, 6, 5, 4], [11, 10, 9, 8]]
```

---

The values that you are trying to change are elements of a 1d array.  They are effectively scalar (though wrapped in a numpy dtype):

```
In [455]: x=np.arange(3).astype(np.float64)
In [456]: for j in x:
     ...:     print(j,type(j))
     ...:     j += 1
     ...:     print(j)
     ...:     
0.0 <class 'numpy.float64'>
1.0
1.0 <class 'numpy.float64'>
2.0
2.0 <class 'numpy.float64'>
3.0
In [457]: x
Out[457]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
```

Or for elements of a flat list:

```
In [462]: x=[0,1,2]
In [463]: for j in x:
     ...:     j += 1
     ...:     
In [464]: x
Out[464]: [0, 1, 2]
```

In my example above I just changing rows of a 2d array.  The values change within the loop, but they don't backpropagate to the source array.

Another example:

```
In [469]: x = np.arange(3)
In [470]: y = x[0]
In [471]: y += 1
In [472]: y
Out[472]: 1
In [473]: x
Out[473]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [474]: x[0] += 1
In [475]: x
Out[475]: array([1, 1, 2])
```

The iteration `j` is more like the `y=x[0]` case than the `x[0]+=` one.

Comment: Thank your for the insight.  I think I understand the name assignment issue, and with that in mind, I've updated my example to be more reflective of the issue I'm having.  Please take a look if you can.  Since I'm using *+=* and */=*, shouldn't the underlying value get updated?

Comment: In my example, the source is 2d, and the `j` a 1d array; in your case a 1d array and a 'scalar' value.  I added some examples that may help show the difference.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bad idea to reset the index in a for loop

secondly you loop accomplishes nothing as written, since neither A nor B is  in the body

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't really have "C-style" pointers, but names that can point at objects. Sometimes the objects can change, so the data the name refers to will change (mutable objects). Sometimes the objects can't, so you need to create a new one and re-point the name at it (immutable objects).

The output from `zip` that you bind to `i` and `j` in your loop are immutable values. Saying `j = i` will just point *the name* `j` at `i`, but won't do anything to the *object formerly known as `j`* (which still exists as part of `B`).

If you want to copy portions of arrays around, use slices then Numpy can do it for you very efficiently (see [*Indexing — NumPy User Guide*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html)):

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
B = np.zeros_like(A)
assert np.all(B == 0)
B[:] = A[:]
assert not np.any(B == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make your examples work with minimal changes (arrows); for a more principled method see bottom of this post:

```
import numpy as np

f = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
trials = [[0,1,2], [5,6,7], [8,9]]
trial_averages = np.zeros(len(trials))
for i, j in zip(trials, trial_averages[:, None]): # <----
    for k in i:
        j += f[k]
    j /= len(i)
print('trials = {0}'.format(trials))
print('averages = {0}'.format(trial_averages))
print('{0}, {1}'.format(i, j))

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=float)
B = np.zeros(len(A))
for i, j in zip(A, B[:, None]):                   # <----
    j[...] = i                                    # <----
print('A = {0}'.format(A))
print('B = {0}'.format(B))
print('{0}, {1}'.format(i, j))
```

Output:

```
trials = [[0, 1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
averages = [ 2.   7.   9.5]
[8, 9], [ 9.5]
A = [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
B = [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
4.0, [ 4.]
```

As you can see in the first example it is enough to make `j` mutable. In the second example we also have to change the assignment into a `__setitem__` controlled one.

A more verbose but less hackish way of creating something like a C pointer are 0d arrays. You can use `np.nditer` to create iterators returning 0d arrays instead of naked values. In many ways they behave like scalars but you can "dereference" them using `[()]` and then assign to them. Your second example would look like this and produce the same output as before:

```
ro, wo, rw = ['readonly'], ['writeonly'], ['readwrite']

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=float)
B = np.zeros(len(A))
for i, j in np.nditer([A, B], [], [ro, wo]): # <----
    j[()] = i                                # <----
print('A = {0}'.format(A))
print('B = {0}'.format(B))
print('{0}, {1}'.format(i, j))
```